# How to join 2 arrays into a third one?

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, for-loop, indexing

I want to add `a1` and `a2` into a third array, `a3`. However, it is not working properly.

When running the following code, the output was:

```
1 2 3 4 5 5 88237492 23928392 23234242 343344.
```

Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 30
int main(){
  int a1[]={1,2,3,4,5};
  int a2[]={1,2,3,4,5};
  int a3[10];
  int i=0;
  int k=0;
  int j=0;
  
  while(i<sizeof(a1)/sizeof(int))
  {
    a3[i]=a1[i];
    i++;
  }

  while(j<sizeof(a2)/sizeof(int))
  {
    a3[i]=a2[j];
    j++;
  }
  while(k<sizeof(a3)/sizeof(int))
  {
    printf("%d ",a3[k]);
    k++;
  }        

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have forgotten (?) to increment `i` in the second `while` loop (the one using the `j` index).

Comment: In the second while loop, try incrementing i (i++) also after incrementing j (j++)

Comment: Debugging fail:(  You should learn how to use a debugger or, at least, understand that you can printf out the values of inportant vars such as array indices.

Answer (score 1):

I think other have already answered this question but I want to add one more thing that can help you in future. As you have declared array using `int a3[10] = {}`. This will initialize your array with zeros. Then It becomes easy to debug.

If you have used this format then output of you program will be `[1,2,3,4,5,5,0,0,0,0]` so then it becomes easy to debug that after 5 values are not assigning. So it is easy to visualize and will save time.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your second loop. You are repeatedly assigning the values of `a2` to `a3[5]` (`i` is stuck at 5). The rest of `a3` remains uninitialised, hence the weird values.

You also may want to use for loops for this kind of things

Answer (score 0):

As the question is regarding `joining two array's into third one`. If you want a efficient alternative, you can directly copy the memory of each array using `memcpy()` from `string.h` header file. But you should be very careful on how you use it, since you could overwrite any other existing data which could cause a `segmentation fault`. Please find the complete implementation below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int a1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int a2[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17};
    int a3[17] = {0}; //initializes all elements to 0.

    //make a3
    memcpy(a3, a1, sizeof(a1));
    memcpy(&a3[sizeof(a1)/sizeof(int)], a2, sizeof(a2));

    //print a3
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(a3)/sizeof(int); i++)
        printf("%d\n", a3[i]);

    return 0;
}
```